# Create custom notification event Carttrob

Tags: php, expressionengine, cartthrob

If I need to create a custom notification event, that sends an email when the user arrives to the `ORDER SUMMARY` page (coming from `CHECKOUT` page, but I don't think that matter) what should I do?

I found this on the documentation: https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/developers/notifications/index.html#registering-an-event

But is necessary to create an extension or a module only for an event?

Can you provide me a very basic example on how can I create an event and how can I call it on the order_summary.html ? Maybe an `EE` tag?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with Vector, the people behind CartThrob)

You'll definitely need some kind of custom code to create a custom event. Typically yes, that'd be in the form of an extension or module.

That said, it doesn't need to necessarily be a CartThrob notification in your case. Something like this might work: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/email-from-template

If you want to use CartThrob notifications, you'd have your custom module or extension add the notification type to CartThrob as shown on the page you linked. Then on the summary page you'd have a tag from your custom module, and that tag's logic would fire the notification.

If you need more help with this it's certainly something we can build for you. Feel free to email us at support@cartthrob.com!